# Salesforce -Moving metadata showing error at the time of deploy

Tags: salesforce, metadata, apex, visualforce, force-ide

I am trying to move metadata through ANT tool, data also retrieved but at the time of deploying the data to another sandbox it is showing error like :

All Component Failures:

1. triggers/AfterUpdateOnOpportunity.trigger -- Error: Invalid type: OpportunityEventProcessor (line 6, column 3)
2. triggers/BeforeInsertOnTierInfo.trigger -- Error: Invalid type: Schema.Tier_Info__c (line 1, column 9)
3. triggers/BeforeInsertOnAggregateRates.trigger -- Error: Invalid type: Schema.Aggregate_Rate__c (line 1, column 9)

*********** DEPLOYMENT FAILED ***********

Can you please suggest me, where I am going wrong at the deploying process:

```
<project name="Sample usage of Salesforce Ant tasks" default="test" basedir="." xmlns:sf="antlib:com.salesforce">

<property file="build.properties"/>
<property environment="env"/>

<!-- Setting default value for username, password and session id properties to empty string 
     so unset values are treated as empty. Without this, ant expressions such as ${sf.username}
     will be treated literally.
-->
<condition property="sf.username" value=""> <not> <isset property="sf.username"/> </not> </condition>
<condition property="sf.password" value=""> <not> <isset property="sf.password"/> </not> </condition>
<condition property="sf.sessionId" value=""> <not> <isset property="sf.sessionId"/> </not> </condition>

<taskdef resource="com/salesforce/antlib.xml" uri="antlib:com.salesforce">
    <classpath>
        <pathelement location="../ant-salesforce.jar" />          
    </classpath>
</taskdef>

<!-- Test out deploy and retrieve verbs for package 'mypkg' -->
<target name="test">
  <!-- Upload the contents of the "mypkg" package -->
  <sf:deploy username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" sessionId="${sf.sessionId}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" maxPoll="${sf.maxPoll}" deployRoot="mypkg" rollbackOnError="true"/>
  <mkdir dir="retrieveOutput"/>
  <!-- Retrieve the contents into another directory -->
  <sf:retrieve username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" sessionId="${sf.sessionId}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" maxPoll="${sf.maxPoll}" retrieveTarget="retrieveOutput" packageNames="MyPkg"/>
</target>

<!-- Retrieve an unpackaged set of metadata from your org -->
<!-- The file unpackaged/package.xml lists what is to be retrieved -->
<target name="retrieveUnpackaged">
  <mkdir dir="retrieveUnpackaged"/>
  <!-- Retrieve the contents into another directory -->
  <sf:retrieve username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" sessionId="${sf.sessionId}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" maxPoll="${sf.maxPoll}" retrieveTarget="retrieveUnpackaged" unpackaged="unpackaged/package.xml"/>
</target>

<!-- Retrieve all the items of a particular metadata type -->
<target name="bulkRetrieve">
  <sf:bulkRetrieve username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" sessionId="${sf.sessionId}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" maxPoll="${sf.maxPoll}" metadataType="${sf.metadataType}" retrieveTarget="retrieveUnpackaged"/>
</target>

<!-- Retrieve metadata for all the packages specified under packageNames -->
<target name="retrievePkg">
  <sf:retrieve username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" sessionId="${sf.sessionId}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" maxPoll="${sf.maxPoll}" retrieveTarget="retrieveOutput" packageNames="${sf.pkgName}"/>
</target>

<!-- Deploy the unpackaged set of metadata retrieved with retrieveUnpackaged and run tests in this organization's namespace only-->
<target name="deployUnpackaged">
  <sf:deploy username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" sessionId="${sf.sessionId}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" maxPoll="${sf.maxPoll}" deployRoot="retrieveUnpackaged" rollbackOnError="true"/>
</target>

<!-- Deploy a zip of metadata files to the org -->
<target name="deployZip">
  <sf:deploy username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" sessionId="${sf.sessionId}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" maxPoll="${sf.maxPoll}" zipFile="${sf.zipFile}" pollWaitMillis="1000" rollbackOnError="true"/>
</target>

<!-- Shows deploying code & running tests for code in directory -->
<target name="deployCode">
  <!-- Upload the contents of the "codepkg" directory, running the tests for just 1 class -->
  <sf:deploy username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" sessionId="${sf.sessionId}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" maxPoll="${sf.maxPoll}" deployRoot="codepkg" testLevel="RunSpecifiedTests" rollbackOnError="true">
     <runTest>SampleDeployClass</runTest> 
  </sf:deploy>
</target>
```

```
<!-- Shows removing code; only succeeds if done after deployCode -->
<target name="undeployCode">
  <sf:deploy username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" sessionId="${sf.sessionId}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" maxPoll="${sf.maxPoll}" deployRoot="removecodepkg"/>
</target>

<!-- Shows retrieving code; only succeeds if done after deployCode -->
<target name="retrieveCode">
  <!-- Retrieve the contents listed in the file codepkg/package.xml into the codepkg directory -->
  <sf:retrieve username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" sessionId="${sf.sessionId}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" maxPoll="${sf.maxPoll}" retrieveTarget="codepkg" unpackaged="codepkg/package.xml"/>
</target>

<!-- Shows deploying code, running all tests, and running tests (1 of which fails), and logging. -->
<target name="deployCodeFailingTest">
  <!-- Upload the contents of the "codepkg" package, running all tests -->
  <sf:deploy username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" sessionId="${sf.sessionId}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" maxPoll="${sf.maxPoll}" deployRoot="codepkg" testLevel="RunAllTestsInOrg" rollbackOnError="true" logType="Debugonly"/>
</target>

<!-- Shows check only; never actually saves to the server -->
<target name="deployCodeCheckOnly">
  <sf:deploy username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}" sessionId="${sf.sessionId}" serverurl="${sf.serverurl}" maxPoll="${sf.maxPoll}" deployRoot="codepkg" checkOnly="true"/>
</target>
```

This is my build.xml code is here